# How to have a block element display after all inline elements in a row without breaking them into separate lines

Tags: css

On my webpage, I want to have fixed size inline icons that can break to the next line like normal depending on the screen width, like this:
[image: Just Icons]

When a user clicks one of these icons, I want to open up a block element below that line of icons. So if a user clicked "Icon 4" it would look like this:
[image: What I want]

However, the block, which comes directly after its respective icon in the html, may cause the icons to break when it is displayed, which is expected given the order. 
[image: What I currently have]

My first thought would be to use flex boxes and the order property, but it looks like I would have to do some calculations to figure out the order, which is something that I want to avoid.

**Is it possible to achieve the results in the second image with CSS alone?**

And here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```js
function iconClicked(contentId) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        document.getElementById('content'+i).style.display='none';
    }
    document.getElementById('content'+contentId).style.display='block';
}
```

```css
.container {    
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.container * {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: none; /* Changed to block by javascript */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(0)">Icon 0</p>
    <p class="content" id="content0">Content 0</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(1)">Icon 1</p>
    <p class="content" id="content1">Content 1</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(2)">Icon 2</p>
    <p class="content" id="content2">Content 2</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(3)">Icon 3</p>
    <p class="content" id="content3">Content 3</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(4)">Icon 4</p>
    <p class="content" id="content4">Content 4</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(5)">Icon 5</p>
    <p class="content" id="content5">Content 5</p>

    <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(6)">Icon 6</p>
    <p class="content" id="content6">Content 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? Your snippet seems to be running as intended for me (Chrome 60, macOS Sierra)

Comment: Not at all possible to achieve the second image using CSS only. But I think the third one is possible to achieve.

Comment: The medium screen configuration on the 2nd image doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to detect if row can show 2 item or more, if yes then move current content after `content5`

```js
function iconClicked(contentId) {
  for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    document.getElementById('content' + i).style.display = 'none';
  }
  w = window,
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    content = document.getElementById('content' + contentId);

  if(x > 640) {
    pNode = document.getElementById('content5');
    pNode.parentNode.insertBefore(content, pNode.nextSibling);
  }
  content.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container * {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  /* Changed to block by javascript */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(0)">Icon 0</p>
  <p class="content" id="content0">Content 0</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(1)">Icon 1</p>
  <p class="content" id="content1">Content 1</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(2)">Icon 2</p>
  <p class="content" id="content2">Content 2</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(3)">Icon 3</p>
  <p class="content" id="content3">Content 3</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(4)">Icon 4</p>
  <p class="content" id="content4">Content 4</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(5)">Icon 5</p>
  <p class="content" id="content5">Content 5</p>

  <p class="icon" onclick="iconClicked(6)">Icon 6</p>
  <p class="content" id="content6">Content 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! It looks like the general consensus is that such a thing isn't possible with CSS alone, but your answer helped me get to the results I was looking for. Thank you!